# Date is wrong when JS passed a Date in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, date, laravel-5, vuejs2

I am using Laravel 5.7 and I am having a problem with the date string being passed from JS to PHP.

Before I passed the date in Vue JS and I put a `console.log()` to see the actual value and I have this:

`Fri Feb 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)`

and then when I receive it to Laravel Controller, I `\Log::info()` to show the value being received but I have this:

`2019-01-31T16:00:00.000Z`

does anyone encountered the same problem and managed to fix it? Please help

Comment: Can you share more details? How do you send the data to the backend? Do you parse or manipulate it somehow? Usually, a string is a string and should not get changed in such way. Additionally, what is your real **problem** with this?

Comment: As shown below those dates are the same just showing different timezones. Keeping that in mind, what problem are you facing?

Comment: `Fri Feb 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)` is exactly the same moment in time as `2019-01-31T16:00:00.000Z` ... one is Pillippine Stanard Time, the other is UTC

Comment: @NicoHaase I passed it using axios post

Answer (score 0):

It's not different date, just ISO formatted when you convert date into string.

you can create the date object again using new  Date()

```js
let date = new Date()
console.log(date)
console.log(date.toString())
let date2 = new Date(date.toString())
console.log(date2)
```

Comment: And what do you suggest to change?

Comment: whats the issue?  it's not asked what is the problem with the converted format.

Comment: the problem I got is when the date is being passed in the controller, it will have january (`2019-01-31T16:00:00.000Z`) instead of february

Comment: It's the same date time, you've had multiple people tell you this now.

Comment: @Imperatura you will have to manage the timezone offset in your code if needed.